# Flutter place a button in the middle of BottomNavigationBar Widget

Tags: flutter

I have this code.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant_menu),
        title: Text('Recipes'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.list),
        title: Text('Plans'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
        title: Text('Groceries'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        title: Text('Account'),
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation:
      FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterDocked,
);
```

It looks like this.

[image]

The button I want it in the middle of the BottomNavigationBar. I want inside of it
like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a solution for this, you can make it by using container and build it from scratch + using row
In this case you can using Center widget

Don't forget to make a property called extend in scaffold to be true

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a floating action button, you can just add another BottomNavigationBarItem, and set the title to be a container with no height (that way the title is effectively null, but won't cause an issue with the BottomNavigationItem requiring a non-null title), as well as set the color.
e.g.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
   icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 40, color: Colors.blue,),
   title: Container(height: 0.0,)
),
```